# Where do i go next to populate answer for binary to decimal program?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, binary

[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFUEA.png) <---How i am informed to complete program

I have been working on this forever now.  I am required to create Constants then declare and initiate each then multiplying each by it's place value (128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1)

I know Integer.parseINT(Binary....) would do the job quickly however I CANNOT USE IT.

followed is what i have thus far, am i even on the right track?  I know i need to get each of the separated user input values and have them multiplied by their place values then added to create the decimal but i for the life of me cannot figure out how to do it through for loop or defining each variable

```
...
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Binary {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Binary Number Please");
        Integer[] digits = getDigits(keyboard.nextInt());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
    }

    public static Integer[] getDigits(int num) {
        List <Integer> digits = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        collectDigits(num, digits);
        return digits.toArray(new Integer[]{});
    }

    private static void collectDigits(int num, List <Integer> digits) {
       if (num/10>0) {
            collectDigits(num/10, digits);
        }
        digits.add(num % 10);
    }
}
```

I am wanting to separate each character of the user input binary so i can have them multiplied by their place value, then each product added to create the sum that will then be displayed to the user via `System.out.println()`

Comment: @Creative - I have read that over and over and over and cannot figure out how to declare and initialize the variables taken from ''Integer[] digits = getDigits(keyboard.nextInt());"
also,  i am sure i need to somehow implement instring.charAt() to pull those values but again...how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise, if you were not required to transform every digit into a constant variable before multiplying it, the following code would solve your problem entirely:

```
public class Binary {

    private static int placeValue = 1;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Binary Number Please");
        Integer[] digits = getDigits(keyboard.nextInt());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
        System.out.println("Sum: " + getSum(digits));
        keyboard.close();
    }

    public static Integer[] getDigits(int num) {
        List <Integer> digits = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        collectDigits(num, digits);
        return digits.toArray(new Integer[]{});
    }

    private static void collectDigits(int num, List <Integer> digits) {
       if (num/10>0) {
            collectDigits(num/10, digits);
        }
        digits.add(num % 10);
    }

    private static int getSum(Integer[] digits)
    {
        int result = 0;

        for(int i=(digits.length-1); i>=0; i--)
        {
            result += (digits[i] * placeValue);
            placeValue *= 2;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Outputs, taking 8 digits:

Enter Binary Number Please

11011011

[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

Sum: 219

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this, to generate the required constants at runtime. Using the static initializer:

```
public class PseudoConstant {

    public static final int PSEUDO_CONSTANT;
    private static final Random randomGen = new Random();

    static {
         PSEUDO_CONSTANT = generatePsudoConstant();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PseudoConstant instance1 = new PseudoConstant();
        PseudoConstant instance2 = new PseudoConstant();

        System.out.println("PSEUDO_CONSTANT (instance1) = " + instance1.PSEUDO_CONSTANT);
        System.out.println("PSEUDO_CONSTANT (instance2) = " + instance2.PSEUDO_CONSTANT);
    }

    private static int generatePsudoConstant() {
        return randomGen.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```